# How to carry Xtracycle by car?

Tags: cargo, car-rack

What is the best way to mount an Xtracycle to the roof of your car?

Xtracycle has a [few suggestions](http://blog.xtracycle.com/news/2014/12/4/transporting-your-bike-by-car-or-train-bus-or-plane) particilary a Thule or RockyMounts Tandem rack.

We have a Mazda CX-9 with factory cross bars.  The problem with Xtracycle's suggestion is it will cost around $800 to buy all that gear.  We are looking for a cheaper option.

We were considering the [Sea Sucker Talon](https://www.seasucker.com/shop/1187/).   That looks like it might work.  It will be a task to get the big bike on to the roof of the car but we will only be doing this occasionally.

Our bike is a converted Bianchi which looks similar to [this one](http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3022/2972060489_54b18e37d2.jpg?v=1234240169).  It's around 50+lbs.

Comment: Where there's a will, [there's a way](http://www.smartcarofamerica.com/gallery/files/1/3/9/6/3/smart_tandem_rack_original.jpg)

Comment: @Kibbee That's awesome!

Comment: My theory is: don't. Use a rear mounted rack instead. Bike on the roof costs so much extra fuel and sooner or later many people forget it's there and drive into a carport. The result is that the bike is a write-off *and* so is the car.

Comment: @Kibbe Can you make that into an answer?

Comment: If the length of the bike is legal, a hitch rack, or get a rack fabricated that holds the bike vertically off the hitch, Strop the top roof the rack back to the roof bars. For ideas have a look at [here](http://www.tandem-bicycle-central.com/hitch-rack.html) and talk to an engineering shop.

Answer (score 2):

If the length of the bike is makes it legal, hitch rack with the bike sticking out would be the cheapest and easiest - You would be no wider than trailers and trucks, but care would be need to remember that. Get a rack fabricated that holds the bike vertically off the hitch, Strop the top roof the rack back to the roof bars. For ideas have a look at here and talk to an engineering shop.

Have a look for ideas to carry tandems - [Here is one idea that would work](http://cloggy.brinkster.net/).